# How to fix this MVC error when adding a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

I have this error when trying to add a new controller to my MVC app:

**Visual Studio 2019 4.7.2 .NET Framework**

**Error:**

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The value -1
>   is 
>       outside the acceptable range of [0,2147483647].
>       Parameter name: value'

I tried to restart Visual Studio but it didn't work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Add the exact versions of the .NET Framework and VS at the very least.  Reproduce with a new, minimal MVC app.

Comment: Tried shutting down all running copies of Visual Studio and **deleting all temporary files from your project/solution folders**, before restarting Visual Studio and trying again?

Comment: Seems like the same issue as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39127199/there-was-an-error-running-the-selected-code-generator-object-reference-not-se

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 4.7.2 .NET Framework